# C# while loop not working for some reason

Tags: c#, while-loop

I'm sure that this is just some silly thing my tired eyes are not seeing so please have a look:

```
int NoteCounter = 0;
int MaxNotes = 100;
string SongSegment = "";
Random NoteIndexGen = new Random();

while (NoteCounter <= MaxNotes)
{
    int NoteIndex = NoteIndexGen.Next(1, 7);
    #region SetNotes
    switch (Key)
    {
        case "C-Maj":
            switch (NoteIndex)
            {
                case 1:
                    SongSegment += "  C  ";
                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    SongSegment += "  D  ";
                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    SongSegment += "  E  ";
                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    SongSegment += "  F  ";
                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    SongSegment += "  G  ";
                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    SongSegment += "  A  ";
                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                    break;
                case 7:
                    SongSegment += "  B  ";
                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case "G-Mag":
            switch (NoteIndex)
            {
                case 1:
                    SongSegment += "  G  ";
                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    SongSegment += "  A  ";
                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    SongSegment += "  B  ";
                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    SongSegment += "  C  ";
                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    SongSegment += "  D  ";
                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    SongSegment += "  E  ";
                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                    break;
                case 7:
                    SongSegment += "  F#  ";
                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case "D-Maj":
            switch (NoteIndex)
            {
                case 1:
                    SongSegment += "  D  ";
                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    SongSegment += "  E  ";
                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    SongSegment += "  F#  ";
                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    SongSegment += "  G  ";
                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    SongSegment += "  A  ";
                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    SongSegment += "  B  ";
                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                    break;
                case 7:
                    SongSegment += "  C#  ";
                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case "A-Maj":
            switch (NoteIndex)
            {
                case 1:
                    SongSegment += "  A  ";
                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    SongSegment += "  B  ";
                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    SongSegment += "  C#  ";
                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    SongSegment += "  D  ";
                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    SongSegment += "  E  ";
                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    SongSegment += "  F#  ";
                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                    break;
                case 7:
                    SongSegment += "  G#  ";
                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case "E-Maj":
            switch (NoteIndex)
            {
                case 1:
                    SongSegment += "  E  ";
                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    SongSegment += "  F#  ";
                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    SongSegment += "  G#  ";
                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    SongSegment += "  A  ";
                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    SongSegment += "  B  ";
                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    SongSegment += "  C#  ";
                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                    break;
                case 7:
                    SongSegment += "  D#  ";
                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }
    NoteCounter++;
    #endregion SetNotes

    #endregion GenerateMusic
    break;
}
```

You may have figured out that I am making a random music generator kind of thing that I will later expand on, but in order for that to work, I need the notes to be added to the string `SongSegment`

The output in the `RichTextBox` is only one note though, like so:

```
  A
```

See anything I didn't catch?

Comment: Your last `break;` should be deleted.

Comment: Your eyes are probably tired due to the excessive indentation.

Comment: The debugger (used on the actual code, not the incomplete, non-compilable excerpt you posted here) should be able to figure this out pretty quickly. As you've not provided an actual [mcve], it's pretty difficult for us to say, particularly when you provide that horrendously indented and partial mass of code.

Comment: You know it's time for refactoring when you have regions in a method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var SongSegments = new Dictionary<char, string[]>() { 
    { 'C', "C D E F G A B".Split(' ') }, 
    { 'G', "G A B C D E F#".Split(' ') }, 
    { 'D', "D E F# G A B C#".Split(' ') }, 
    { 'A', "A B C# D E F# G#".Split(' ') }, 
    { 'E', "E F# G# A B C# D#".Split(' ') } };

OutputInfo1.Text = string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(new Random(), 100)
               .Select(r => "  " + SongSegments[Key[0]][r.Next(0, 6)] + "  "));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that, the switch statements are a pain and I've been using them excessively and an alternative is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

As @Ken Y-N mentioned in a comment above, delete the last `break` statement. That breaks out of the while loop and means the loop will execute at most once.

Answer (score 1):

ppl are true the end `break;` is wrong and ofc your code needs some optimizations too I think :

```
int NoteCounter = 0;
int MaxNotes = 100;
string SongSegment = "";
Random NoteIndexGen = new Random();

while (NoteCounter <= MaxNotes)
{
    int NoteIndex = NoteIndexGen.Next(1, 7);
    #region SetNotes
    switch (Key)
    {
        case "C-Maj":
            switch (NoteIndex)
            {
                case 1:
                    SongSegment += "  C  ";                        
                    break;
                case 2:
                    SongSegment += "  D  ";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    SongSegment += "  E  ";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    SongSegment += "  F  ";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    SongSegment += "  G  ";
                    break;
                case 6:
                    SongSegment += "  A  ";
                    break;
                case 7:
                    SongSegment += "  B  ";
                    break;
            }
            OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
            break;
        case "G-Mag":
            switch (NoteIndex)
            {
                case 1:
                    SongSegment += "  G  ";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    SongSegment += "  A  ";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    SongSegment += "  B  ";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    SongSegment += "  C  ";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    SongSegment += "  D  ";
                    break;
                case 6:
                    SongSegment += "  E  ";
                    break;
                case 7:
                    SongSegment += "  F#  ";
                    break;
            }
            OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
            break;
        case "D-Maj":
            switch (NoteIndex)
            {
                case 1:
                    SongSegment += "  D  ";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    SongSegment += "  E  ";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    SongSegment += "  F#  ";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    SongSegment += "  G  ";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    SongSegment += "  A  ";
                    break;
                case 6:
                    SongSegment += "  B  ";
                    break;
                case 7:
                    SongSegment += "  C#  ";
                    break;
            }
            OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
            break;
        case "A-Maj":
            switch (NoteIndex)
            {
                case 1:
                    SongSegment += "  A  ";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    SongSegment += "  B  ";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    SongSegment += "  C#  ";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    SongSegment += "  D  ";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    SongSegment += "  E  ";
                    break;
                case 6:
                    SongSegment += "  F#  ";
                    break;
                case 7:
                    SongSegment += "  G#  ";
                    break;
            }
            OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
            break;
        case "E-Maj":
            switch (NoteIndex)
            {
                case 1:
                    SongSegment += "  E  ";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    SongSegment += "  F#  ";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    SongSegment += "  G#  ";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    SongSegment += "  A  ";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    SongSegment += "  B  ";
                    break;
                case 6:
                    SongSegment += "  C#  ";
                    break;
                case 7:
                    SongSegment += "  D#  ";
                    break;
            }
            OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
            break;
    }
    NoteCounter++;
    #endregion SetNotes

    #endregion GenerateMusic

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is because you are using break; an extra time in the end ....

```
                int NoteCounter = 0;
                int MaxNotes = 100;
                string SongSegment = "";
                Random NoteIndexGen = new Random();

                while (NoteCounter <= MaxNotes)
                {
                    int NoteIndex = NoteIndexGen.Next(1, 7);
                    #region SetNotes
                    switch (Key)
                    {
                        case "C-Maj":
                            switch (NoteIndex)
                            {
                                case 1:
                                    SongSegment += "  C  ";
                                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                                    break;
                                case 2:
                                    SongSegment += "  D  ";
                                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                                    break;
                                case 3:
                                    SongSegment += "  E  ";
                                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                                    break;
                                case 4:
                                    SongSegment += "  F  ";
                                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                                    break;
                                case 5:
                                    SongSegment += "  G  ";
                                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                                    break;
                                case 6:
                                    SongSegment += "  A  ";
                                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                                    break;
                                case 7:
                                    SongSegment += "  B  ";
                                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                                    break;
                            }
                            break;
                        case "G-Mag":
                            switch (NoteIndex)
                            {
                                case 1:
                                    SongSegment += "  G  ";
                                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                                    break;
                                case 2:
                                    SongSegment += "  A  ";
                                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                                    break;
                                case 3:
                                    SongSegment += "  B  ";
                                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                                    break;
                                case 4:
                                    SongSegment += "  C  ";
                                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                                    break;
                                case 5:
                                    SongSegment += "  D  ";
                                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                                    break;
                                case 6:
                                    SongSegment += "  E  ";
                                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                                    break;
                                case 7:
                                    SongSegment += "  F#  ";
                                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                                    break;
                            }
                            break;
                        case "D-Maj":
                            switch (NoteIndex)
                            {
                                case 1:
                                    SongSegment += "  D  ";
                                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                                    break;
                                case 2:
                                    SongSegment += "  E  ";
                                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                                    break;
                                case 3:
                                    SongSegment += "  F#  ";
                                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                                    break;
                                case 4:
                                    SongSegment += "  G  ";
                                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                                    break;
                                case 5:
                                    SongSegment += "  A  ";
                                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                                    break;
                                case 6:
                                    SongSegment += "  B  ";
                                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                                    break;
                                case 7:
                                    SongSegment += "  C#  ";
                                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                                    break;
                            }
                            break;
                        case "A-Maj":
                            switch (NoteIndex)
                            {
                                case 1:
                                    SongSegment += "  A  ";
                                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                                    break;
                                case 2:
                                    SongSegment += "  B  ";
                                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                                    break;
                                case 3:
                                    SongSegment += "  C#  ";
                                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                                    break;
                                case 4:
                                    SongSegment += "  D  ";
                                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                                    break;
                                case 5:
                                    SongSegment += "  E  ";
                                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                                    break;
                                case 6:
                                    SongSegment += "  F#  ";
                                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                                    break;
                                case 7:
                                    SongSegment += "  G#  ";
                                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                                    break;
                            }
                            break;
                        case "E-Maj":
                            switch (NoteIndex)
                            {
                                case 1:
                                    SongSegment += "  E  ";
                                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                                    break;
                                case 2:
                                    SongSegment += "  F#  ";
                                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                                    break;
                                case 3:
                                    SongSegment += "  G#  ";
                                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                                    break;
                                case 4:
                                    SongSegment += "  A  ";
                                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                                    break;
                                case 5:
                                    SongSegment += "  B  ";
                                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                                    break;
                                case 6:
                                    SongSegment += "  C#  ";
                                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                                    break;
                                case 7:
                                    SongSegment += "  D#  ";
                                    OutputInfo1.Text = SongSegment;
                                    break;
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                    NoteCounter++;
                    #endregion SetNotes

                    #endregion GenerateMusic
                }
```